# Airline seating algorithm: how to seat a passenger in mirror image to previous allocated seat

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a seat allocation algorithm for an airplane 30 x 6 seats.
The plane is 'split' front (1 - 15) and back (16 -30), right (A,B,C) and left (D,E,F). I am placing passengers in window seats front right centre (15A) first then back left centre (16F) followed by (15F) followed by (16A). This will continue for single passengers middle seats then aisle.

Another part of the algorithm is to ensure parties >2 or <=6  to sit together in an empty row, if not possible the party will be split as to not have a person in the party sitting alone firstly. i.e. 6  is 3 + 3  or 2 + 2 + 2 or 4 + 2 or 3 + 2 + 1 or 4 + 1 + 1 or 3 + 1 + 1 + 1  and so.

I am wondering if anyone has any input to maybe refactor it, a different approach to allocating seats on an airline taking into consideration load and grouping parties or any other thoughts?  I have been asked that if there is a manual selection of 1A - 1F  will the alogrithm mirror this and place six passengers automatically to the back 30A -30F or next clear row.  Is this possible?  All comments welcome.

```
using ARS.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ARS.Controllers 
{
    public class DemoSeatController : Controller
    {
        const int seatCapacity = 180;
        const int maxRow = 6;
        const int maxCol = 30;

        const int middleCols = maxCol / 2;
        const int middleRows = maxRow / 2;

        int countFrontPlane = 0, countBackPlane = 0, countLeftPlane = 0, countRightPlane = 0;

        // GET: DemoSeat
        public ActionResult DemoSeat()
        {
            ViewBag.PartySizeDDL = new SelectList(populatePartySizeDDL(), "Value", "Text", "1");
            return View();
        }

        //Post: DemoSeat
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult DemoSeat(int party)
        {
            //create list of seats
            List<Seat> seats = new List<Seat> { };
            SeatSelectionController ssc = new SeatSelectionController();
            SeatRepository seatRepo = new SeatRepository();
            seats = ssc.GetAllSeats().ToList();
            //create Seat array from list
            bool[,] seatArray = new bool[maxCol, maxRow];

            //set variable for list index
            int i = 0;
            //populate the 2d array from grid list and counts reserved seats front, back, left and right in middle of plane
            for (int row = 0; row < maxRow; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < maxCol; col++)
                {
                    seatArray[col, row] = seats.ElementAt(i).IsReserved;
                    if (seats.ElementAt(i).IsReserved)
                    {
                        if (col < middleCols)
                        {
                            countFrontPlane++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            countBackPlane++;
                        }
                        if (row < middleRows)
                        {
                            countRightPlane++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            countLeftPlane++;
                        }
                    }
                    i++;
                }
            }

            int freeSeats = seatCapacity - (countFrontPlane + countBackPlane);
            //Algorithm
            if (party <= freeSeats)
            {

                //switch statment
                switch (party)
                {
                    case 6:
                        seatArray = seatSixPerson(seatArray, countFrontPlane <= countBackPlane ? middleCols - 1 : middleCols, countFrontPlane <= countBackPlane ? 0 : maxCol, countFrontPlane <= countBackPlane ? -1 : 1, countRightPlane <= countLeftPlane ? 0 : maxRow - 1, countRightPlane <= countLeftPlane ? maxRow : 0, countRightPlane <= countLeftPlane ? 1 : -1);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        seatArray = seatFivePerson(seatArray, countFrontPlane <= countBackPlane ? middleCols - 1 : middleCols, countFrontPlane <= countBackPlane ? 0 : maxCol, countFrontPlane <= countBackPlane ? -1 : 1, countRightPlane <= countLeftPlane ? 0 : maxRow - 1, countRightPlane <= countLeftPlane ? maxRow : 0, countRightPlane <= countLeftPlane ? 1 : -1);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        seatArray = seatFourPerson(seatArray, countFrontPlane <= countBackPlane ? middleCols - 1 : middleCols, countFrontPlane <= countBackPlane ? 0 : maxCol, countFrontPlane <= countBackPlane ? -1 : 1, countRightPlane <= countLeftPlane ? 0 : maxRow - 1, countRightPlane <= countLeftPlane ? maxRow : 0, countRightPlane <= countLeftPlane ? 1 : -1);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        seatArray = seatThreePerson(seatArray, countFrontPlane <= countBackPlane ? middleCols - 1 : middleCols, countFrontPlane <= countBackPlane ? 0 : maxCol, countFrontPlane <= countBackPlane ? -1 : 1, countRightPlane <= countLeftPlane ? 0 : maxRow - 1, countRightPlane <= countLeftPlane ? maxRow : 0, countRightPlane <= countLeftPlane ? 1 : -1);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        seatArray = seatTwoPerson(seatArray, countFrontPlane <= countBackPlane ? middleCols - 1 : middleCols, countFrontPlane <= countBackPlane ? 0 : maxCol, countFrontPlane <= countBackPlane ? -1 : 1, countRightPlane <= countLeftPlane ? 0 : maxRow - 1, countRightPlane <= countLeftPlane ? maxRow : 0, countRightPlane <= countLeftPlane ? 1 : -1);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        seatArray = seatOnePerson(seatArray, countFrontPlane <= countBackPlane ? middleCols - 1 : middleCols, countFrontPlane <= countBackPlane ? 0 : maxCol, countFrontPlane <= countBackPlane ? -1 : 1, countRightPlane <= countLeftPlane ? 0 : maxRow - 1, countRightPlane <= countLeftPlane ? maxRow : 0, countRightPlane <= countLeftPlane ? 1 : -1);
                        break;

                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Default case");
                        break;
                }

                i = 0;
                for (int row = 0; row < maxRow; row++)
                {
                    for (int col = 0; col < maxCol; col++)
                    {
                        seats.ElementAt(i).IsReserved = seatArray[col, row];
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.PartySizeDDL = new SelectList(populatePartySizeDDL(), "Value", "Text", "1");
                ViewBag.Error = "NO SEATS";
                return View();
            }
            seatRepo.UpdateReservedStatus(seats);
            ViewBag.PartySizeDDL = new SelectList(populatePartySizeDDL(), "Value", "Text", "1");
            return View();
        }

        #region HelperMethods
        //seat allocation for one person
        public bool[,] seatOnePerson(bool[,] seatArray, int startCol, int endCol, int directionX, int startRow, int endRow, int directionY)
        {
            //loop through seatArray section determined by parameters
            for (int col = startCol; directionX < 0 ? col >= endCol : col < endCol; col += directionX)
            {
                for (int row = startRow; directionY < 0 ? row >= endRow : row < endRow; row += directionY)
                {
                    //if free seat at first location
                    if (!seatArray[col, row])
                    {
                        //count seats current column
                        int countLeft = 0, countRight = 0;
                        for (int currentRow = 0; currentRow < maxRow; currentRow++)
                        {
                            if (seatArray[col, currentRow])
                            {
                                if (currentRow < middleRows)
                                {
                                    countRight++;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    countLeft++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        //if column is empty
                        if (countRight == countLeft && countRight == 0)
                        {
                            //if right side of plane has more passengers than left
                            if (countRightPlane > countLeftPlane)
                            {
                                //start seating on the left from the window seat
                                for (int currentRow = maxRow - 1; currentRow >= 0; currentRow--)
                                {
                                    if (!seatArray[col, currentRow])
                                    {
                                        seatArray[col, currentRow] = true;
                                        return seatArray;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            //if left side of plane has more passengers than right
                            else
                            {
                                //start seating on the right from the window seat
                                for (int currentRow = 0; currentRow < maxRow; currentRow++)
                                {
                                    if (!seatArray[col, currentRow])
                                    {
                                        seatArray[col, currentRow] = true;
                                        return seatArray;
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        }
                        //if column is not empty and more seats on the right hand side of the column than the left
                        else if (countRight > countLeft)
                        {
                            //if more passengers seated on the right than the left
                            if (countRightPlane >= countLeftPlane)
                            {
                                //start seating on the left from the window seat
                                for (int currentRow = maxRow-1; currentRow >= 0; currentRow--)
                                {
                                    if (!seatArray[col, currentRow])
                                    {
                                        seatArray[col, currentRow] = true;
                                        return seatArray;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            //if left side of plane has more passengers than right
                            else
                            {
                                //start seating on the right from the window seat
                                for (int currentRow = 0; currentRow < maxRow; currentRow++)
                                {
                                    if (currentRow < middleRows)
                                    {
                                        if (!seatArray[col, currentRow])
                                        {
                                            seatArray[col, currentRow] = true;
                                            return seatArray;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    // else
                                    //{
                                    // col --;
                                    //   break;
                                    // }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        //if column is not empty and more seats on the left hand side of the column than the right
                        else
                        {
                            //if right side of plane has more passengers than left
                            if (countRightPlane > countLeftPlane)
                            {
                                //start seating on the left from the window seat
                                for (int currentRow = maxRow - 1; currentRow >= 0; currentRow--)
                                {
                                    //if row currently trying to seat is on the left
                                    if (currentRow >= middleRows)
                                    {
                                        //seat passenger
                                        if (!seatArray[col, currentRow])
                                        {
                                            seatArray[col, currentRow] = true;
                                            return seatArray;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    //else continue loop with col++
                                }
                            }
                            //if left side of plane has more passengers than right
                            else
                            {
                                //start seating on the right from the window seat
                                for (int currentRow = 0; currentRow < maxRow; currentRow++)
                                {
                                    if (!seatArray[col, currentRow])
                                    {
                                        seatArray[col, currentRow] = true;
                                        return seatArray;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return seatArray;
        }
        //seat allocation for two people
        public bool[,] seatTwoPerson(bool[,] seatArray, int startCol, int endCol, int directionX, int startRow, int endRow, int directionY)
        {
            for (int row = startCol; directionX < 0 ? row >= endCol : row < endCol; row += directionX)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < maxRow - 1; col++)
                {
                    if (!seatArray[row, col] && !seatArray[row, col + 1])
                    {
                        seatArray[row, col] = true;
                        seatArray[row, col + 1] = true;
                        return seatArray;
                    }
                }
            }
            seatArray = seatOnePerson(seatArray, 0, maxCol, directionX, 0, maxRow, 1);
            seatArray = seatOnePerson(seatArray, 0, maxCol, directionX, 0, maxRow, 1);
            return seatArray;
        }
        //seat allocation for three people
        public bool[,] seatThreePerson(bool[,] seatArray, int startCol, int endCol, int directionX, int startRow, int endRow, int directionY)
        {
            for (int row = startCol; directionX < 0 ? row >= endCol : row < endCol; row += directionX)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < maxRow - 2; col++)
                {
                    if (!seatArray[row, col] && !seatArray[row, col + 1] && !seatArray[row, col + 2])
                    {
                        seatArray[row, col] = true;
                        seatArray[row, col + 1] = true;
                        seatArray[row, col + 2] = true;
                        return seatArray;
                    }
                }
            }
            //seatArray = seatTwoPerson(seatArray, 0, maxCol);
            seatArray = seatOnePerson(seatArray, 0, maxCol, directionX, 0, maxRow, 1);
            return seatArray;
        }
        //seat allocation for four people
        public bool[,] seatFourPerson(bool[,] seatArray, int startCol, int endCol, int directionX, int startRow, int endRow, int directionY)
        {
            for (int row = startCol; row < endCol; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < maxRow - 3; col++)
                {
                    if (!seatArray[row, col] && !seatArray[row, col + 1] && !seatArray[row, col + 2] && !seatArray[row, col + 3])
                    {
                        seatArray[row, col] = true;
                        seatArray[row, col + 1] = true;
                        seatArray[row, col + 2] = true;
                        seatArray[row, col + 3] = true;
                        return seatArray;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (canSeatTwoPersonNTimes(seatArray, 2))
            {
                seatArray = seatTwoPerson(seatArray, 0, maxCol, directionX, 0, maxRow, 1);
                seatArray = seatTwoPerson(seatArray, 0, maxCol, directionX, 0, maxRow, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                seatArray = seatThreePerson(seatArray, 0, maxCol, directionX, 0, maxRow, 1);
                seatArray = seatOnePerson(seatArray, 0, maxCol, directionX, 0, maxRow, 1);
            }
            return seatArray;
        }
        //seat allocation for five people
        public bool[,] seatFivePerson(bool[,] seatArray, int startCol, int endCol, int directionX, int startRow, int endRow, int directionY)
        {
            for (int row = startCol; row < endCol; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < maxRow - 4; col++)
                {
                    if (!seatArray[row, col] && !seatArray[row, col + 1] && !seatArray[row, col + 2] && !seatArray[row, col + 3] && !seatArray[row, col + 4])
                    {
                        seatArray[row, col] = true;
                        seatArray[row, col + 1] = true;
                        seatArray[row, col + 2] = true;
                        seatArray[row, col + 3] = true;
                        seatArray[row, col + 4] = true;
                        return seatArray;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (canSeatThreeAndTwoPerson(seatArray))
            {
                seatArray = seatThreePerson(seatArray, 0, maxCol, directionX, 0, maxRow, 1);
                seatArray = seatTwoPerson(seatArray, 0, maxCol, directionX, 0, maxRow, 1);
            }
            else if (canSeatTwoPersonNTimes(seatArray, 2))
            {
                seatArray = seatTwoPerson(seatArray, 0, maxCol, directionX, 0, maxRow, 1);
                seatArray = seatTwoPerson(seatArray, 0, maxCol, directionX, 0, maxRow, 1);
                seatArray = seatOnePerson(seatArray, 0, maxCol, directionX, 0, maxRow, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                seatArray = seatThreePerson(seatArray, 0, maxCol, directionX, 0, maxRow, 1);
                seatArray = seatTwoPerson(seatArray, 0, maxCol, directionX, 0, maxRow, 1);
            }
            return seatArray;
        }
        //seat allocation for six people
        public bool[,] seatSixPerson(bool[,] seatArray, int startCol, int endCol, int directionX, int startRow, int endRow, int directionY)
        {
            for (int row = startCol; row < endCol; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < maxRow - 5; col++)
                {
                    if (!seatArray[row, col] && !seatArray[row, col + 1] && !seatArray[row, col + 2] && !seatArray[row, col + 3] && !seatArray[row, col + 4] && !seatArray[row, col + 5])
                    {
                        seatArray[row, col] = true;
                        seatArray[row, col + 1] = true;
                        seatArray[row, col + 2] = true;
                        seatArray[row, col + 3] = true;
                        seatArray[row, col + 4] = true;
                        seatArray[row, col + 5] = true;
                        return seatArray;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (canSeatThreePersonNTimes(seatArray, 2))
            {
                seatArray = seatThreePerson(seatArray, 0, maxCol, directionX, 0, maxRow, 1);
                seatArray = seatThreePerson(seatArray, 0, maxCol, directionX, 0, maxRow, 1);
            }
            else if (canSeatTwoPersonNTimes(seatArray, 3))
            {
                seatArray = seatTwoPerson(seatArray, 0, maxCol, directionX, 0, maxRow, 1);
                seatArray = seatTwoPerson(seatArray, 0, maxCol, directionX, 0, maxRow, 1);
                seatArray = seatTwoPerson(seatArray, 0, maxCol, directionX, 0, maxRow, 1);
            }
            else if (canSeatThreeAndTwoPerson(seatArray))
            {
                seatArray = seatThreePerson(seatArray, 0, maxCol, directionX, 0, maxRow, 1);
                seatArray = seatTwoPerson(seatArray, 0, maxCol, directionX, 0, maxRow, 1);
                seatArray = seatOnePerson(seatArray, 0, maxCol, directionX, 0, maxRow, 1);
            }
            else if (canSeatTwoPersonNTimes(seatArray, 2))
            {
                seatArray = seatTwoPerson(seatArray, 0, maxCol, directionX, 0, maxRow, 1);
                seatArray = seatTwoPerson(seatArray, 0, maxCol, directionX, 0, maxRow, 1);
                seatArray = seatTwoPerson(seatArray, 0, maxCol, directionX, 0, maxRow, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                seatArray = seatThreePerson(seatArray, 0, maxCol, directionX, 0, maxRow, 1);
                seatArray = seatThreePerson(seatArray, 0, maxCol, directionX, 0, maxRow, 1);
            }
            return seatArray;
        }
        public List<SelectListItem> populatePartySizeDDL()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
            items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "1", Value = "1", });
            items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "2", Value = "2" });
            items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "3", Value = "3" });
            items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "4", Value = "4" });
            items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "5", Value = "5" });
            items.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "6", Value = "6" });

            ViewBag.PartySizeDDL = new SelectList(items, "Value", "Text", "1");
            return items;
        }
        //check to see if you can seat two 'n' times
        public bool canSeatTwoPersonNTimes(bool[,] seatArray, int n)
        {
            int count = 0;

            for (int row = 0; row < maxCol; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < maxRow - 2; col++)
                {
                    if (!seatArray[row, col] && !seatArray[row, col + 1])
                    {
                        count++;
                        if (count >= n) return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        //check to see if you can seat three and two people
        public bool canSeatThreeAndTwoPerson(bool[,] seatArray)
        {
            bool threeVacantSeats = false;

            for (int row = 0; row < maxCol; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < maxRow - 2; col++)
                {
                    if (!seatArray[row, col] && !seatArray[row, col + 1] && !seatArray[row, col + 2])
                    {
                        seatArray[row, col] = true;
                        seatArray[row, col + 1] = true;
                        seatArray[row, col + 2] = true;
                        threeVacantSeats = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (threeVacantSeats)
            {
                for (int row = 0; row < maxCol; row++)
                {
                    for (int col = 0; col < maxRow - 2; col++)
                    {
                        if (!seatArray[row, col] && !seatArray[row, col + 1])
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        //check to see if you can seat three and three people
        public bool canSeatThreePersonNTimes(bool[,] seatArray, int n)
        {
            int count = 0;

            for (int row = 0; row < maxCol; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < maxRow - 2; col++)
                {
                    if (!seatArray[row, col] && !seatArray[row, col + 1] && !seatArray[row, col + 2])
                    {
                        count++;
                        if (count >= n) return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing to consider. It would be more intuitive to look at the plane as 30 rows and 6 columns.  This gives the aspect of standing at the front of the plane in the aisle.  This more intuitively fits in with the front,back,left,right descriptions as well.  The way you have it(6 rows and 30 columns), you're standing beside the plane and looking through the wall.

Comment: Do you have any test cases, esp ones that demonstrate how this is to be used?

Comment: No test cases @abuzittingillifirca sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have business logic in the controller, which you shouldn't. There are people that may have said it OK. It's not.

I have extracted methods twice from you `DemeSeat` method. First removing dependency to the web frameworks, and a second time that removed dependency on model. That method may be tested, as it should, in isolation.

There is these horrible lines:

```
                        seatArray = seatSixPerson(seatArray, countFrontPlane <= countBackPlane ? middleCols - 1 : middleCols, countFrontPlane <= countBackPlane ? 0 : maxCol, countFrontPlane <= countBackPlane ? -1 : 1, countRightPlane <= countLeftPlane ? 0 : maxRow - 1, countRightPlane <= countLeftPlane ? maxRow : 0, countRightPlane <= countLeftPlane ? 1 : -1);
```

If a line is longer than 80 and it can be shortened, that it should be. If it a line is longer than 100-120 it definitely should. My editor says above line is 360+ long.

Above line is also mostly copy-pasted, several times. I had to use search&replace to make sure there wasn't any subtle differences between them.

Here party is a method parameter:

```
switch (party)
// .....

default:
    Console.WriteLine("Default case");
    break;
```

If 1..6 is the only valid `party` throw and `ArgumentException` for all others.

More than a few parameters are a code smell.
Here:
        public bool[,] seatTwoPerson(bool[,] seatArray, int startCol, int endCol, int directionX, int startRow, int endRow, int directionY)

`int startCol, int endCol, int directionX, int startRow, int endRow, int directionY` appear together everywhere give that concept a name and use it:

```
public class SearchBox
{
    public int startCol;
    public int endCol;
    public int directionX;

    public int startRow;
    public int endRow;
    public int directionY;
}
```

Your `SeatNPerson` methods both modify its first parameter, `seatArray`, and return it. A method should either modify something and return nothing, or vice versa. (Command/Query Separation). In this case they should declare `void` return type. By `C#` convention you can merge `bool canSeatX` and `void SeatX`, if there is significant gain to be had, with a method `bool TrySeatX`.

The main routine after some refactorings:

```
void SeatParty(ref List<Seat> seats, int party)
{
    bool[,] seatArray = new bool[maxCol, maxRow];
    int i = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < maxRow; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < maxCol; col++) {
            seatArray[col, row] = seats.ElementAt(i).IsReserved;
            if (seats.ElementAt(i).IsReserved) {
                if (col < middleCols) {
                    countFrontPlane++;
                } else {
                    countBackPlane++;
                }
                if (row < middleRows) {
                    countRightPlane++;
                } else {
                    countLeftPlane++;
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
    }

    int freeSeats = seatCapacity - (countFrontPlane + countBackPlane);

    SeatArray(seatArray, i, freeSeats, party);

    {
    i = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < maxRow; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < maxCol; col++) {
            seats.ElementAt(i).IsReserved = seatArray[col, row];
            i++;
        }
    }
    }

}

bool SeatParty(bool[,] seatArray, int i, int freeSeats, int party)
{
    if (party < 1 || party > 6) throw new ArgumentException("blah");

    if (party > freeSeats)
    {
        return false;
    }

    int startCol = countFrontPlane <= countBackPlane ? middleCols - 1 : middleCols;
    int endCol = countFrontPlane <= countBackPlane ? 0 : maxCol; 
    int directionX = countFrontPlane <= countBackPlane ? -1 : 1;
    int startRow = countRightPlane <= countLeftPlane ? 0 : maxRow - 1;
    int endRow = countRightPlane <= countLeftPlane ? maxRow : 0;
    int directionY = countRightPlane <= countLeftPlane ? 1 : -1;

    var searchBox = new SearchBox
    {
        startCol = startCol,
        endCol = endCol,
        directionX = directionX,
        startRow = startRow,
        endRow = endRow,
        directionY = directionY,
    };


    Action<bool[,], Box>[] actions = {null, 
        seatOnePerson, seatTwoPerson,
        seatThreePerson, seatFourPerson,
        seatFivePerson, seatSixPerson};

    actions[party](seatArray, searchBox);

    return true;
}
```

`SeatNPerson` methods should be looked at; after there is a test harness, however basic, in place; and after some clean up as shown above is done. As they are too complicated to hold in one's mind, what they are doing and all they are doing and if they are doing it correct etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your `i` index variables are scoped a bit larger than they need to be. This happens in several places, but this is a simple example.

> ```
>         i = 0;
>         for (int row = 0; row < maxRow; row++)
>         {
>             for (int col = 0; col < maxCol; col++)
>             {
>                 seats.ElementAt(i).IsReserved = seatArray[col, row];
>                 i++;
>             }
>         }
> ```

As it is, `i` is still alive after the loop has ended. Also, doing it this way means that you have to manually increment the index. You should declare and initialize it in the loop header and let the language do the work.

```
for (int row = 0, int i = 0; row < maxRow; row++, i++)
{
    // inner loop
}
```

Some may say that the extra index variable is superfluous, but I actually like that you've realized that even though `i` and `row` always hold the same value, they represent different things.

---

This would be a good place to throw an exception.

> ```
>         default:
>             Console.WriteLine("Default case");
>             break;
> ```

Reaching the default case here shouldn't ever happen. Right? Then isn't that *exceptional* behavior? If I'm wrong and the idea is simply to break, then a good comment is in order to let the maintainer know that you considered the default case and no action is appropriate.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm sorry I didn't touch on your algorithm. I'm sure it wasn't the review you had hoped for.